# Is raw brined pork with a very slight yellow tint and is no longer limp spoiled?

Tags: pork, brining, spoilage

I put some pork chops in a brine solution almost 48 hours ago, put it in a metal bowl, covered the top of the bowl with plastic wrap and stuck it all in the fridge.

I pulled it out to wash, but I was washing I noticed that there was a very slight yellowing of the meat further from the bone.  As I washed it, I also noted that the pork chop held its form and didn't really flop around like I would expect raw meat to.

Is it still good to grill?

Answer (score 1):

Color and texture are not reliable indicators of food safety.  You have to think freshness, temperature and environment.  If the pork has been kept in the refrigerator the entire time (under 40 degrees F), then it is likely safe to eat (given that you haven't kept is around for days before you brined it)...add to that, a briney environment...relatively high in salt content...You are not going to grow anything nasty in that.  I would say they are safe to grill, although, that's a bit long for a brine on pork chops. "No longer limp" tells me that you've begun to cure them in the brine.